# How to use a function that accepts string indexed type with typescript interface that doesn't have string indexes?

Tags: typescript, types, node-redis

I'm using `node-redis` package to store and retrieve some stats objects. This is part of my code:

```js
export interface ServiceStats {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly startTime: number;
  readonly timestamp: number;
  readonly hostName: string;
  readonly network: number;
  readonly upTime: number;
  readonly stateUpdate?: boolean;
}

async setServiceStats(serviceId: string, stats: ServiceStats) {
  this.client.json.set(serviceId, '$', stats); //     <---- This line has error
}
```

It generates this error because ServiceStats does not have a index signature.

```
 Type at position 2 in source is not compatible with type at position 2 in target.
      Type 'ServiceStats' is not assignable to type 'RedisJSON'.
        Type 'ServiceStats' is not assignable to type 'RedisJSONObject'.
          Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'ServiceStats'.ts(2345)
```

**I can add `stats as any` and error is gone.**

**Or add string indexes to all values that I store**

### But How can I fix this without using `any` or changing the interface?

(The real ServiceStats is more complex and has multiple hierarchies but it's still a valid JSON)

Answer (score 0):

The set function accepts a RedisJSON type as 3rd parameter.
The RedisJSON type is definied as follows:

```
interface RedisJSONArray extends Array<RedisJSON> {}
interface RedisJSONObject {
    [key: string]: RedisJSON;
    [key: number]: RedisJSON;
}
export type RedisJSON = null | boolean | number | string | Date | RedisJSONArray | RedisJSONObject;
```

Your interface ServiceStats is not compatible.

You can solve it by parsing it as string or by using the spread operator

```
this.client.json.set(serviceId, '$', JSON.stringify(stats)); 
this.client.json.set(serviceId, '$', {...stats});
```

You could also redefine your interface so that the index signature is matched but I guess this is less than desiderable

```
export interface ServiceStats {
    [key: string]:  null | boolean | number | string | Date ;
    readonly id: string;
    readonly startTime: number;
    readonly timestamp: number;
    readonly hostName: string;
    readonly network: number;
    readonly upTime: number;
    readonly stateUpdate: boolean;
  }
```